# Wix Toolset copy file issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, wix3.6

I am new to wix and am havaingsome issues using the copyfile component in wix. Please can you loke at the code below and advise. Many Thanks in advanced.

I have 3 features, 3 componentgroups & 3 components as described below with the respective directoryRef

```
<Feature Id = "F1" Title "T1" Level ="1">
  <ComponetGroupRef Id="CG1" />
  <Condition Level="1">
    <![CDATA[ComputerName="S1"]
  </Condition>
</Feature>

<Feature Id = "F1" Title "T1" Level ="1">
  <ComponetGroupRef Id="CG2" />
  <Condition Level="1">
    <![CDATA[ComputerName="S2"]
  </Condition>
</Feature>

<Feature Id = "F1" Title "T1" Level ="1">
  <ComponetGroupRef Id="CG3" />
  <Condition Level="1">
    <![CDATA[ComputerName="S3"]
  </Condition>
</Feature>

<ComponentGroup id="CG1">
  <ComponentRef id="c1" />
</ComponentGroup>

<ComponentGroup id="CG2">
  <ComponentRef id="c2" />
</ComponentGroup>

<ComponentGroup id="CG3">
  <ComponentRef id="c1" />
  <ComponentRef id="c2" />
</ComponentGroup>

<DirectoryRef Id"ApplicationDirectory">
  <Component Id="C1" Guid="xyz">
    <File Id="F1"KeyPath="yes" Source="Some Source Location">
      <CopyFile Id="CF1" DestinationDirectory="Dest1" />
    </File>
  </Component>
  <Component Id="C2" Guid="abc">
    <File Id="F2"KeyPath="yes" Source="Some Source Location">
      <CopyFile Id="CF2" DestinationDirectory="Dest2" />
    </File>
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

so basically if I am running the wix msi on server S1 only File F1 should be copied, when I am running on server S2 only File F2 should be copied and when I am running on Server S3, Files F1 & F2 both should be copied.

The issue I am having is that all the files are being copied irrespictive or server name match.

Can you please advise if I am being foolish.

Thanks,
Janak

Comment: do you have the directory hierarchy in your fragment? where is dest1/2 defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wix is not for copy. 
I defined a different wix template project for the work I wanted to do. So instead of copy from destination to another location. I changed the project implementation so that it copies from source to a different destination.